# Code explanation

Tags: c

I don't know if this is the correct SE site for posting, but i'll try either way,
from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array/).It is suggested that this

```
if (data[c] >= 128)
     sum += data[c];
```

can turn into this:

```
int t = (data[c] - 128) >> 31;
sum += ~t & data[c];
```

Can someone explain to me how this would work?

Comment: StackOverflow would have been marginally better. Perhaps some kind moderator will migrate this for you. Otoh, I am sure that it will be answered on this site too.

Comment: BTW, that looks like unsafe/unportable code as that >> 31 is making an assumption about the number of bis in an integer.  Also, if code is difficult to understand, then it will be difficult to maintain, so best avoid the fancy stuff (of course, you are seeking an explanation here, but I recommend that your own code KISSes)

Comment: @Mawg it's not code that I'll copy paste. I've just read this interesting answer to this interesting question where this change was suggested, and I would like to know how this works

Comment: and it has dangers with integer underflow that the original didn't have

Comment: guys I see you understand it enough to point out why it's unsafe, though noone posts an answer

Comment: Yes. The question simply does not belong here, and thus should not be answered.

Comment: OMG it's like pretentious-ishity at its highest. If you know the answer just post it, it won't cost you anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea behind what is happening is this. Assume data[c] > 128.  If that is true, doing data[c] - 128 results in a positive number (ie. the sign bit is 0).  Shifting that right 31 times results in a number that is all 0s in binary. So t=00000000000000000000000000000000.

Now, when we do ~t it becomes all 1s and &-ing that with data[c] just gives us data[c] again.  Now we add that to the sum and that works just like before.

But what if data[c] < 128?  Well that means that data[c] - 128 is negative, giving a 1 as a sign bit.  Which means that t=11111111111111111111111111111111.  Thus ~t is all 0s.  &-ing all 0s with data[c] just gives all 0s again (ie. 0 in decimal).  Adding 0 to the sum doesn't change it so all is well.